# Is Set in Swift 1.2 thread safe? If not how can I make it thread safe?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a crash that seems to happen on the remove function in Swift 1.2's Set. I'm guessing it isn't thread safe. How can I make it thread safe or is there an alternative that is thread safe?
Thanks!

EDIT: It is defined as a static var in a struct.

Here is the code:

```
struct Syncer {
    static var isSyncing = Set<HKQuantityType>()
}

Syncer.isSyncing.remove(quantityType)
```

Comment: I believe constants define with "let" are thread safe,

Comment: Edited to update that it was defined as a static var in a struct.

Comment: could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not thread safe.
You can try to always access/update if from the same thread. Or protect it with locks, semaphores, etc.