# How to make thread safe code block in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, locking

I tried multiple solution/answers given on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. Some of them is as below :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30495424/3145189

[Is this safe to call wait() of DispatchSemaphore several times at one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49148555/3145189)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37155631/3145189

I am trying to achieve very simple thing, code block or function should execute serially, regardless of from which thread it's been called.

My Example code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.testLog(name:"first")
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.testLog(name:"second")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.testLog(name: "mainthread")
    }
}


func testLog(name:String) -> Void {
        for i in 1..<1000 {
            print("thread test \(i) name =\(name)")
        }

    }
```

So output should be like -

**first thread call**

thread test 1 name =first

thread test 2 name =first

thread test 3 name =first

.

.

.

thread test 999 name =first

**second thread call**

thread test 1 name =second

thread test 2 name =second

.

.

.

thread test 999 name =second

**main thread call**

thread test 1 name =mainthread

thread test 2 name =mainthread

.

.

.

thread test 999 name =mainthread

If function is called on first thread, it should continue print log for the first thread only. Order of thread can vary I don't care means even if it's print mainthread log first then second and first doesn't matter logs should be grouped.

Comment: i have tried multiple things, but not mentioned in example code in my question, so requesting you please test you answer before posting

Comment: create a serial queue and add testLog()  to the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to achieve very simple thing, code block or function should execute serially, regardless of from which thread it's been called.

To execute serially you use a Dispatch serial queue. If you were writing a class or struct you could use a `static let` at class/struct level to store your queue in which your serialising function could dispatch to. A `static let` in this case is equivalent to a "class variable" in some languages.

If you were writing in (Objective-)C such variables can also be declared at the function level, that is a variable with global lifetime but with scope limited to within the function. Swift does not support these within a function, but you can scope a struct to a function...

```
func testLog(name:String) -> Void
{
   struct LocalStatics
   {
      static let privateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "testLogQueue")
   }

   // run the function body on the serial queue - could use async here
   // and the body would still run not interleaved with other calls but
   // the caller need not wait for it to do so 
   LocalStatics.privateQueue.sync {
      for i in 1..<1000
      {
         print("thread test \(i) name =\(name)")
      }
   }
}
```

(For a debate on "local statics" in Swift see [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354882/static-function-variables-in-swift))

Answer (score 3):

This will execute the calls serially.
Keep a reference to `serialQueue` and you can submit blocks from any thread.

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial_queue")

    serialQueue.async {
        self.testLog(name: "first")
    }
    serialQueue.async {
        self.testLog(name: "second")
    }

    serialQueue.async {
        self.testLog(name: "third")
    }
```

Comment: Can do like->  serialQueue.async {
        self.testLog(name: "first") self.testLog(name: "second") self.testLog(name: "third") 
    } in one async block only.

Comment: that is true, but i was trying to demo that each `async` call can be made from different threads in different places in the code